# How to decipher and troubleshoot error tracebacks?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, anaconda

I've used Python for a few years but still have trouble walking through tracebacks to identify and solve coding inconsistencies.

I was hoping to discuss general practices a fellow coder would use in the context of this example, where the occurrence of two exceptions are listed.

My conda virtual environment is currently on Python v3.7.8, astropy v4.0.1, and numpy v1.19.1 where I've run the code from within a singular cell of a Jupyter notebook.

My approach: I started from the bottom of the traceback as is usually recommended and see the line highlighted in function_base.py. Reading the error, it seems as though a float was passed to linspace, which is expecting an integer.

As a cursory pass at debugging, I went to this file in my local anaconda folder and tried to add a few simple print statements to see which variables specifically seemed to be causing the problem. However, after re-loading the relevant packages and re-running, my added lines do not seem to take effect.

Why might this be? Would others recommend an alternative approach?

Below, I've attached the specific call that causes the error and the corresponding traceback.

```
fit('SED_models/models_r06/Per_fitter_data_test.txt', Per8_filters, apertures, model_dir,
    'output.fitinfotest',
    extinction_law=extinction,
    distance_range=[0.2, 0.3] * u.kpc,
    av_range=[0., 40.], remove_resolved=False)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    116     div = (num - 1) if endpoint else num
--> 117 
    118     # Convert float/complex array scalars to float, gh-3504

TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-101-7fa981ab6b6f> in <module>
     14     extinction_law=extinction,
     15     distance_range=[0.2, 0.3] * u.kpc,
---> 16     av_range=[0., 40.], remove_resolved=False)
     17 
     18 # # Define filters and apertures

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sedfitter/fit.py in fit(data, filter_names, apertures, model_dir, output, n_data_min, extinction_law, av_range, distance_range, output_format, output_convolved, remove_resolved)
    177                     extinction_law=extinction_law, av_range=av_range,
    178                     distance_range=distance_range,
--> 179                     remove_resolved=remove_resolved)
    180 
    181     print(" ------------------------------------------------------------")

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sedfitter/fit.py in __init__(self, filter_names, apertures, model_dir, extinction_law, av_range, distance_range, remove_resolved)
     83 
     84         # Read in models
---> 85         self.models = Models.read(model_dir, self.filters, distance_range=distance_range, remove_resolved=remove_resolved)
     86 
     87         # Add wavelength to filters

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sedfitter/models.py in read(cls, directory, filters, distance_range, remove_resolved)
    141             return cls._read_version_1(directory, filters,
    142                                        distance_range=distance_range,
--> 143                                        remove_resolved=remove_resolved)
    144         else:
    145             return cls._read_version_2(directory, filters,

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sedfitter/models.py in _read_version_1(cls, directory, filters, distance_range, remove_resolved)
    172                 else:
    173                     n_distances = 1 + (np.log10(distance_range_kpc[1]) - np.log10(distance_range_kpc[0])) / modpar['logd_step']
--> 174                     print(n_distances)
    175                     m.distances = np.logspace(np.log10(distance_range_kpc[0]), np.log10(distance_range_kpc[1]), n_distances) * u.kpc
    176                 print("   Number of distances :  %i" % m.n_distances)

<__array_function__ internals> in logspace(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in logspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, base, dtype, axis)
    270                           axis=None):
    271     return (start, stop)
--> 272 
    273 
    274 @array_function_dispatch(_geomspace_dispatcher)

<__array_function__ internals> in linspace(*args, **kwargs)

~/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/function_base.py in linspace(start, stop, num, endpoint, retstep, dtype, axis)
    119     # and make sure one can use variables that have an __array_interface__, gh-6634
    120     start = asanyarray(start) * 1.0
--> 121     stop  = asanyarray(stop)  * 1.0
    122 
    123     dt = result_type(start, stop, float(num))

TypeError: object of type <class 'numpy.float64'> cannot be safely interpreted as an integer.
```

Comment: Do you know about debuggers?

Comment: I've tried pdb somewhat but with limited success. Is there one in particular you would recommend for this case?

Comment: Use not just a debugger, but a full Python IDE. This will let you set breakpoints where you can interactively step into the code and explore variables. It will also make it easier to navigate the traceback (click on a line to jump to it in the code, etc.)

Comment: In this case though, the errors seem to be happening in calls to other internal functions, not my code itself. It isn't obvious to me why my attempt to troubleshoot within those other scripts doesn't seem to work. The updated print statements do show up in subsequent tracebacks...

Comment: I may have accidentally deleted your last response, @user228395. My apologies! Duly noted that editing the internal scripts is bad practice. I think my confusion stems from how to debug this case when all of the files quoted in the traceback are external to the code I'm running, if that makes sense? I have the (likely naive) impression that this error is not as easy to systematically track down "line by line".

Comment: You didn't! I was explaining why editing source files does not affect the run when you don't install with `pip install -e` but then realized you might have edited the files in the `site-packages` directory. Anyway, I'd say it is generally the responsibility of the package maintainer to make sure that understandable errors are produced, but unfortunately this is often enough not the case. You'd then need to install the package from sources, or debug it (possibly with an IDE like PyCharm, Visual Studio, Spyder, etc.). You're facing the daily troubles as a coder! ;)